# Do light sockets burn out?

Tags: electrical

I have 3 outdoor fixtures connected to an older GE Digital Timer. I had problems after installing Great Value 40 watt equivalent LED bulbs. I went back to incandescent and one fixture does not light. Do light sockets burn out?

Comment: Looks like an answer, though I'd frame-challenge the question and suggest instead asking "here's what I'm seeing, how do I determine what happened"

Answer (score 2):

"Burn out" usually means deteriorated in the expected manner to its end of life, and that does not happen to light sockets, but it's probably not what you meant.   Light sockets can become broken, corroded, or warped so the bulb does not make contact, and they can develop loose or broken connections or wires internally.  There are lots of reasons a light socket might stop working, and it's no coincidence if handling the socket by changing a bulb is the straw that broke the socket's back.

To address the most common failures: Turn off the breaker, and inspect the contact inside the socket at its base.  It should be present, it should not be corroded or dirty, and it should be sticking up enough that the bulb will push down on it.   If it's flat against the bottom, pry it up a little with a screwdriver.  If the socket is in a fixture than can be opened and inspected, look inside to see if there are screw terminals on the back of the socket that have become loose or other obvious problems inside the fixture.  Don't rely on the light switch being off when you do this, turn off the breaker.

Answer (score 0):

*The Second Law (Law of Energy Decay) states that every system left to its own devices always tends to move from order to disorder,*

So everything wears out. The normal use of light bulbs should not wear out quickly, but my mere observation is that LED bulbs dissipate heat differently. Particularly the envelope of many LEDs is plastic, which doesn't transfer heat well, so heat is dissipated through the socket. Also poor fitting sockets could suffer excessive heat from arcing.

Another factor is lamp shape. The US uses a 1" lamp socket, now internationally redesignated as E26 (Edison 26mm) normally fed by 120v. Overseas there is an E27 230v socket that is similar, but tip shape and thread taper are slightly different. I have seen lamps advertised as universal voltage that "fit" both 120v and 230v fixtures, but the base just can't fit both sockets perfectly. Your bulbs may not have been marketed by Walmart as universal voltage with a modified base attempting to fit both adequately, but who knows what the manufacturer is actually supplying. A poor fitting bulb could poor heat dissipation and possible arcing.